# Not able to hit external HTTP service via Apache Camel

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, restlet

I have a camel route similar to:

```
<camel:routeContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route>
    <from uri="restlet:/v1/authentication/initiate?restletMethod=post&amp;restletBinding=#queryStringToHeadersRestletBinding"/>
    <to uri="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:20015/login"></to>
</route>
```

Now, after receiving the request from restlet, the camel processor instead of going to `http://xx.xx.xx.xx:20015/login` tries to hit `http://localhost/v1/authentication/initiate` which does not exist and thus I get 404 HTTPOperation failed like:

```
    Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking http://localhost/v1/authentication/initiate with statusCode: 404
    at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.populateHttpOperationFailedException(HttpProducer.java:228) ~[camel-http-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:156) ~[camel-http-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
```

I am able to use the routes at other places successfully. But don't know why it is not hitting the intended destination url in this route definition.
Please help.

Comment: Have you set the `Exchange.HTTP_URI` header previously in the route? Or perhaps that's what Restlet is doing? That would override the value of the uri given in the route

Comment: Remove the CamelHTTP headers which the restlet may cause noise when calling the HTTP endpoint. See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-remove-the-http-protocol-headers-in-the-camel-message.html

Comment: Yes the CamelHTTPHeader was causing the issue which was pointing to the restlet url. Removing the headers worked: `<removeHeaders pattern="CamelHttp*" excludePattern="CamelHttpMethod" />` Thanks to all !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the CamelHTTP headers which the restlet may cause noise when calling the HTTP endpoint.

See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-remove-the-http-protocol-headers-in-the-camel-message.html